# Different way of writing intersection in relational algebra

Tags: intersection, relational-algebra

Using basic operators, derive the additional operator intersection.

R ∩ S = ?

I thought it might be: (R ∪ S) - ((R -S) ∪ (S -R)) but I also think there might be an easier way of doing it?

Comment: Why don't you ask that at [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I'm not sure I should. It is a question that was in our notes for Database Technology module.

Comment: What is given to you as "basic operators"? Intersection is one of the most basic operators to me…

Answer (score 2):

A intersected with B is equal to A - (A - B) or equivalenty B - (B - A)

Answer (score 1):

`R ∩ S` is also equal to `~( (~R) ∪ (~S) )`

where `~A` is the complement of `A`